# Remove all lines from textarea contains specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textarea with text in few lines. I want to remove lines contains specific word, for example "car".

```
<textarea id="test">cars_and_house
tree_and_car
tree_and_house
cat_and_car</textarea>
```

To make textarea looks like that (without empty lines):

```
<textarea id="test">tree_and_house</textarea>
```

I was thinking to start with val.replace, but how can I remove whole line?

```
$( "#test" ).val().replace("car", "") ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split on newline character `\n` and filter out those which contains the word `cat`. Also you need to re-set the value attribute, which you're currently not doing.

```
$('#test').val(function(_, val){
   return val.split("\n").filter(function(line){
      return line && line.indexOf("car") == -1
   }).join("\n");
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But it wasn't word "cat", it was "car" :) Of course, your solution works great.

Comment: @Lucas oh jeez cats!! Anyway, glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is the good old vanilla javascript replace function. jQuery has its own replace function: $.replaceWith().

I would also advice the [online regeular expression tester](https://regex101.com/), which works like a charm and gives very useful feedback.

I think this snippet will work for you:

```
var newValue = $("#test").val().replace(/([\w]?)*car([\w]?)*/gi,"");
$("#test").val(newValue);
```

where *g* searches for more than the first match, and *i* makes it case insensitive.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This: `$( "#test" ).val().replace(/^.*car.*\n?/gim,"");`

return:

```
tree_and_house
```

This: `$( "#test" ).val().replace(/^.*car.*/gim,"");`

return:

```
//empty row 
//empty row
tree_and_house
```

If you need `case sensitive` match remove `i`:

`/^.*car.*/gm`

this not match `Car` or `cAr`